# following text team (not getting desired elements)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Removing following text contains team should fix this but selenium does not detect this element.  Why is it not getting all the elements following team?  Is there a following team + 1 or better way to write this so it gets all elements following team?

I am trying to scrape data from this [website](https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/English_Premier_League/Matches)

Xpath looks like:

groups = `".//table[contains(@class, 'MarketTable MatchMarket')]"`

xp_bp1 = `".//th[contains(text(),'Team')]/following::div[contains(@class, 'MarketGroup')]//table[contains(@class, 'MarketTable MatchMarket')]//tbody//tr[1]//td[1]"`

Output (there are None values instead of desired):

```
[['Tottenham Hotspur', 'West Ham United', '1.25', 'https://www.link'], [None, None, None, 'https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/English_Premier_League/Matches']]
```

Desired:

```
[['Arsenal', 'Chelsea', '3.00', 'https://link'], ['Tottenham Hotspur', 'West Ham United', '1.25', 'https://link']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below xpath for getting team names :

```
 //table[@class='MarketTable MatchMarket']//tbody[1]/tr/td[1]
```

use below xpath for getting team win value:

```
//table[@class='MarketTable MatchMarket']//tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]
```

Comment: That works.  Is what I am after even possible using selenium using following.  Seems to always ignore first set of data.